# Prisma Client Extensions - computed fields returns promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

The new Prisma client extensions provide a way to compute a custom field in the response.

e.g.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    user: {
      // Add a computed field called `nameAndAge` to the user
      nameAndAge: {
        needs: {
          name: true,
          age: true,
        },
        compute(user) {
          return `${user.name} (${user.age}y)` + getdata();
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

const user = await prisma.user.findFirst();
console.log(user?.nameAndAge);
```

However, I want to call an async function from within the client like this:

```js
async function getdata(){
  return "external data here!"
}

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    user: {
      // Add a computed field called `nameAndAge` to the user
      nameAndAge: {
        needs: {
          name: true,
          age: true,
        },
        compute(user) {
          return `${user.name} (${user.age}y)` + getdata();
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

const user = await prisma.user.findFirst();
console.log(user?.nameAndAge);
```

However, this always returns a promise and I can't `await` the `getdata()` function in the return.

e.g.

```
Sonia Lomo (25y)[object Promise]
```

Is there a solution to this somehow ?

I also tried making the `compute` function asynchronous then awaiting the `getdata()` function. e.g.:

```js
async compute(user) {
          return `${user.name} (${user.age}y)` + await getdata();
        },
```

However, the promise always returns as pending.

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this `prisma` contributor in this issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/18300#issuecomment-1468303756)

> This is works as intended. Purpose of result extensions is to add synchronously computed field to the model with minimum overhead, so it can be queried implicitly

Also the [official doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/client-extensions/result#considerations-for-fields) specifies

> For performance reasons, Prisma Client computes results on access, not on retrieval.

I've struggles too with this limitation of prisma and my solution was to simply return an `async` function as the result of the compute method.
Then the value can be computed when needed.

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
    result: {
        user: {
            getNameAndAge: {
                needs: { name: true, age: true },
                compute(user) {
                    return async () => (`${user.name} (${user.age}y) ${await getdata()}`)
                },
            },
        },
    },
})

// ...when needed

const joeNameAndAge = await users[0].getNameAndAge()
```

On the other hand you can define a custom specific for that model that queries and manipulate the data as you need.

You can find more [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/client-extensions/model).

```js
export type UserFindManyWithData = {
    where: Prisma.UserWhereInput
    select: Prisma.UserSelect
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
    model: {
        user: {
            async findManyWithData({ where, select }: UserFindManyWithData) {
                const users = await prisma.user.findMany({ where, select })
                
                // This is not the best strategy for performance, ideally you would like to await all promises at once, but it depends on your project
                for (const user of users) {
                    user.nameAndAge = `${user.name} (${user.age}y) ${await getdata()}`
                }
                
                return users
            },
        },
    },
})
```